# Convert Epoch Date in Date time format 1980-01-01

Tags: java, android, date-format, epoch

This is my code

```
private Date getReferenceDate(int seg) {

    switch (seg) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            return new Date(1980-01-01);
        case 31:
        case 32:
        case 33:
            return new Date(1970-01-01);
        default:
            return new Date(1980-01-01);
    }
}

 private Date getDateFormat(int time, int seg) {
    Date date = getBaseReferenceDate(seg);
    date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + time);
    date.setHours(date.getHours() - 5);
    date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - 30);
    date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds()-1);
    return date;
}
```

I have Date in 1185106460 format
i want to convert it into 2017-07-21 12:14:20 this format
I get Wrong output for 1980-01-01

Comment: That’s unclear, sorry. Do you mean that if `seg` is 1, 2 or 3, then you want to add 1185106460 seconds to a base of 1980-01-01? And then perform some adjustment for time zone? I am just giessing here.

Comment: if seg is 1,2,3 i want date format 1980-01-01 1185106460 is time that pass  date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + time);
    date.setHours(date.getHours() - 5);
    date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - 30);
    date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds()-1);

Comment: It didn’t make it much clearer. Also your desired format includes only date, but the result you say you want includes time of day too. Which do you really want?

Comment: i want date ...basically i get output 2007-7-22 which is in 1970-01-01 format but i want output 2017-7-21 in 1980-01-01 format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following is what you want.

Even though you are on Android and thus don’t have the modern Java date and time API built-in, I am using it because it’s much more convenient, in particular for this kind of operation. You get it in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

```
private static OffsetDateTime getReferenceDate(int seg) {
    int baseYear = 1970;
    if (seg >= 31 && seg <= 33) {
        baseYear = 1980; 
    }
    return OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(baseYear, Month.JANUARY, 1), 
                             LocalTime.MIDNIGHT,
                             ZoneOffset.UTC);
}

private static OffsetDateTime getDateFormat(int time, int seg) {
    return getReferenceDate(seg).plusSeconds(time);
}
```

See it work:

```
    System.out.println(getDateFormat(1185106460, 1));
```

This prints:

```
2007-07-22T12:14:20Z
```

This is the date and time you asked for.

If you want just the date in yyyy-mm-dd format:

```
    System.out.println(getDateFormat(1185106460, 1)
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
```

This prints

```
2007-07-22
```

If you need an outdated `Date` object, for example for some legacy API that you cannot change:

```
    System.out.println(DateTimeUtils.toDate(getDateFormat(1185106460, 1).toInstant()));
```

On my computer this prints:

```
Sun Jul 22 14:14:20 CEST 2007
```

It’s the same point in time, only `Date.toString()` formats it into the JVM’s time zone setting. In Java 8 or later the conversion would be

```
    System.out.println(Date.from(getDateFormat(1185106460, 1).toInstant()));
```

**What were you doing wrong?** First, you were using the deprecated methods in `Date`. These were deprecated for a reason, they are unreliable across time zones, so you don’t want to use them. You may also have intended to use one of the deprecated `Date` constructors, but you are using the non-deprecated one. `1980-01-01` is an arithmetic expression with two subtractions. `01` is an octal integer literal with the value 1, so the result of the expression is 1978. You pass the 1978 into the constructor `Date(long date)`, where they are interpreted as milliseconds since the epoch, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

In the case where you intended the mentioned epoch as reference, you are getting close, just 1968 milliseconds off. I suspect that your subtraction of 1 second in the end is your attempt to compensate for this. In the case where you intended the 1980 reference, you are 10 years off, save 1978 milliseconds. Which lead to this question.

In any case, `Date` is long outdated and not suited for what you are trying to do. I recommend ThreeTenABP as I said. If you really, really don’t want to rely on an external library (just until the modern API comes to Android), you may look into the `Calendar` and/or `GregorianCalendar` classes, but they are troublesome and errorprone, just be warned.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir I can understand my mistake

Answer (score -1):

You can convert long date in date by following:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String date=dateFormat.format(new Date(long timeInMillis));
```